# datetime changing to time [2013-03-08 01:50:31]

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, join

I am running a series of queries starting with Selecting all from a view and posting it into a newly-wiped table:

```
DELETE FROM GTMP_PROGRESS
WHERE OBJID IS NOT NULL;

INSERT IGNORE INTO GTMP_PROGRESS
SELECT * FROM GTMP_PROG_VIEW;
```

Those queries work fine. The data in GTMP_PROGRESS looks exactly the same as the data in the view.

THEN- I run a series of JOINs with individual tables to update GTMP_PROGRESS based on criteria. Here are a couple of examples:

```
UPDATE IGNORE GTMP_PROGRESS AS gtmp
JOIN (SELECT cast(EU AS UNSIGNED) AS eu
           , MAX(START_TIME) AS max
           , CLUSTER_COMPLETE AS complete 
      FROM `BENIN_CLEAN` 
      GROUP BY EU) AS benin
ON gtmp.EUID = benin.EU
SET gtmp.Completed_Date = benin.max
WHERE benin.complete>0;

UPDATE IGNORE GTMP_PROGRESS AS gtmp
JOIN (SELECT cast(EU AS UNSIGNED) AS eu
           , MAX(START_TIME) AS max
           , CLUSTER_COMPLETE AS complete 
      FROM `IMPACT_CAMBODIA_CLEAN` 
      GROUP BY EU) AS cambodia
ON gtmp.EUID = cambodia.EU
SET gtmp.Completed_Date = cambodia.max
WHERE cambodia.complete>0;
```

This continues for around 30 joins. At the end of these JOIN queries, I have 577 Completed_Date field entries for the following datetime: "2013-03-08 01:50:31". The EUs with this datetime are NOT the EUs that should be affected by the JOIN queries... these are entries that existed in the original VIEW table. Before these JOIN queries are run, the values for the Completed_Date are either another datetime or the Completed_Date field is NULL.

A bit of history is that these queries worked perfectly before the Completed_Date field underwent a standardization of all of the dates, so that they qualified as datetime fields. The _CLEAN tables always used datetime format exclusively, so I don't know if that could have caused the issue.

I cannot make ANY sense of this.

Comment: Can you do some debugging for this problem? you know of records that are getting the wrong `Completed_Date`, can you run the process again and check one of those records after each update? This will give us exactly one update that causes the problem (perhaps many other do also, but we know this one does). With that and sample data for the EU in question we can get a lot closer to solving your problem.

Comment: This is mysql isn't it? Can't you create a small http://sqlfiddle.com/ that demonstrates your problem. Based on your text it is somewhat unclear.

Comment: I'm trying to add it into sqlfiddle, but it's saying "ERROR! Unable to find consistent column separator in header row"... but I exported it as CSV...?

Comment: I found UPDATE JOIN queries where a ridiculous amount of rows were affected. And then I found 2 where no rows were affected, but should have been. For the ones where too many rows were affected, these happen to be the oldest tables, but I checked the variable formats and they are the same as the others...

Comment: Can you confirm this is mysql?

Comment: yes. I'm doing it in phpmyadmin

Comment: I noticed something... in the ET_OROMIA_CLEAN table (the one from the JOIN, after which everything goes haywire), it assigns the Completed_Date for 577 districts as the datetime of the first record in the list when I open the ET_OROMIA_CLEAN table on its own.